# Function to insert in a #div ajaxed content

Tags: jquery, function, html, insert

Hi friends first of all sorry for my english, ill try to do my best making this question.

Im new to the functions world of jquery, what i want to achieve is this result http://s22.postimg.org/8636pk6ht/menu1.png but dinamicaly made via ajax when page get loaded.

the numbers are the amount of new authorizations to take care of, so if i accept or deny the numbers must be updated dinamicaly

so far i have this

```
$.fn.sucursales = function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax/sucumenu.php",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(response){
            alert(response)
        }
    });
}
```

and im getting this response where num are the amount of new authorizations

```
[{"id":"3","nombre":"Arjona","num":"1"},{"id":"1","nombre":"Cartagena","num":"0"},{"id":"2","nombre":"Turbaco","num":"2"},{"id":"4","nombre":"Turbana","num":"0"}]
```

So the question is. How can i with a function insert this in the div i want doing something like

```
$("#sidebar").sucursales();
```

and update it when I press accept or deny

adding the html of course which I already have. looking like this image http://s22.postimg.org/8636pk6ht/menu1.png

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
$.fn.sucursales = function() {
    var $this = this;

    $.getJSON('ajax/sucumenu.php', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, row) {
            $('<div>', {
                text: row.nombre
            }).appendTo($this);
        });
    });

    return this;
}
```